# Making links and passing parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a link in a page to another show page

here's the code for the link:

```
    <%= link_to c.name, companies_path(:id => c.id) %> # c is the name of my model object
```

here is the route I've set for the show page:

```
    match '/companies/:id', to: 'companies#show'
```

when I type the url `'/companies/:id'` it takes me to the show page like I want but when I click the link it creates `'/companies.":id"'` instead.

Comment: Did you add `resources :companies` in the route.rb file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `c` is a company object that you're trying to link to - you should be able to link to the page you're looking for using `companies_path(c)`, or even just `c`, like so:

```
<%= link_to c.name, companies_path(c) %>
<%= link_to c.name, c %>
```

Comment: thanks alot. that worked. But I also had to change the local variable '@company' in the companies controller to something else. Do you know why that is? I don't think I declared '@company' anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb :

```
resources :companies
```

Then do :

```
<%= link_to c.name, company_path(c.id) %>
```